# Having trouble positioning things in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a beginner to Bootstrap and I'm not really getting the ideas of it 100% clearly yet. I am however kind-of in a rush to push out a content idea for who-ever I'm creating this. Could someone clear some things up for me and if something's changed, perhaps explain what really changed?

I've linked a picture down below to imgur with what the structure looks like now.

On request, i'm explaining the things that were in the picture as text now.

See the 'Language' dropdown? I'd like for that one to be in the top right corner when the devices are full-screen. But when the device is on smaller devices like SM or XS, then it should divert itself into the menu button's expanding menu.

i'd also like for the whole navbar to be centered on its own, as if moving a block of concrete with text on it to a different position.

It'd also be nice if it were possible to have the logo/banner thing up top resize along with the page size. For example: on mobile it would cut the side bars along the picture, and  then have the picture scale down. Bootstrap should have this, but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks sincerely for the help.

PS: Don't comment on the messy code mess with containers, headers, etc. I know it's probably not correct. I'm figuring it out. Thanks for the concern though!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXwYl.jpg

```css
.bg-irie {
    background-color: #E7DD96; 
}

.bg-irie2 {
    background-color: #41403E;
}

.header-advertisement {
    height:320px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/src/img/favicon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Irie Vibes Roots Festival - Home</title>     
    </head>
    <body class="bg-irie">
        <header class="text-center">

            <div class="container-fullwidth bg-irie2">
                <div class="header-advertisement ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BUu5PPO.png">
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-irie2">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Irie Vibes</a>
                        <!--Menu button for small screens-->
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>                        
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    <!--Loading scripts at the end of the page to prevent slowdowns-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to explain your issue in text instead of showing an image. It's a little confusing trying to understand what your issue is.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. You have at least three questions here. You already have one answer that addresses only one of these.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Newly edited and i change the width of the language dropdown and make it as you said,

And position absolute to make the layer as Independent as per the z-index value

```css
.bg-irie {
    background-color: #E7DD96; 
}

.bg-irie2 {
    background-color: #41403E;
}
#navbarDropdownMenuLink, .dropdown-menu{
  text-align: right;
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  color:#fff
}
#navbarNavDropdown{
  text-align: center
}
.dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0 !important;
}
.header-advertisement {
    height:320px;
}
.navbar{
  display: inline-block; !important
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/src/img/favicon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Irie Vibes Roots Festival - Home</title>     

    <body class="bg-irie">
       <header class="text-center">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle pull-right" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language</a>
     
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </div>
            <div class="container-fullwidth bg-irie2">
                <div class="header-advertisement ">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BUu5PPO.png">
                </div>
                <div class="container"> <center>
                    <nav style="display: inline-block" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-irie2">
                   
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Irie Vibes</a>
                        <!--Menu button for small screens-->
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    

                                </li>
                            </ul>                        
                        </div>
                     
                    </nav>
                       </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    <!--Loading scripts at the end of the page to prevent slowdowns-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, looks nice! I haven't tried it yet, though. I do know that Bootstrap has classes like text-left, text-center and text-right. Can I use those instead of the classes you made for those?

Also, what does position Absolute do in this case?

Comment: Hey, just tested it. It's close, but not entirely what I'm looking for. Mainly the language button. I thought of having it **next to** the header image, instead if in a line above it. The navbar is probably fine like this (as I may be able to edit the rest myself.) Oh and it's a bit weird that the whole top bar is clickable, and that the language menu isn't just under the dropdown selector. The dropdown I'm looking for in that corner is near identical to the one that appears in the navbar. And <center> is a bit ancient. c:Thanks for the help already though!

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out markup. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

try this for the banner

Add an id to the image.

```
<img id="BUu" src="http://i.imgur.com/BUu5PPO.png">
</div>
```

Then, add this to your CSS

```
.header-advertisement {
    /* height: 320px; */
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

#BUu {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's a handy thing to do. Thanks for the idea!